# Concatenate two column values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have two columns:

```
colA    colB
a1      b1
NULL    b2
a3      NULL
```

I want to concatenate both columns in a SELECT-query for the following cases:

> if value of `colA is NULL` and `colB is NULL` return `NULL`
>   if value of `colA is NULL` and `colB is NOT NULL` return `:b1`
>   if value of `colA is NOT NULL` and `colB is NULL` return `a1`
>   if `both values are NOT NULL` return `a1:b1`

How can i select the appropriate values for the cases?

Comment: Please show us your code so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT NULLIF(COALESCE(colA,'')+COALESCE(':'+colB,''), '') FROM myTable
```

Some explanation:

`COALESCE` returns the first not-null argument in its argument list. So the first `COALESCE` turns a null `colA` into the empty string.

The second `COALESCE` first prepends a colon to `colB` -- but if `colB` is null, attempting to append a string returns NULL! So the result is again the empty string if `colB` is null, and a colon plus `colB` if it wasn't.

We append the two `COALESCE` outputs. We now have everything the OP wanted, except that if both are null, we have the empty string.  `NULLIF` takes care of that -- if its arguments are equal, it returns NULL, otherwise it returns the first argument.

Comment: oops ... thanks @MatBallie

Comment: Nice solution...

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (cola VARCHAR(100), colb VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(NULL, NULL),
('a1', NULL),
(NULL, 'b1'),
('a1', 'b1');

SELECT NULLIF(CONCAT(cola, ':' + colb), '')
FROM @t
```

```
NULL
a1
:b1
a1:b1
```

Keep in mind that:

- `+` operator yields NULL if any operand is NULL
- `CONCAT` treats NULL values as empty strings
- `NULLIF` is there to handle the special case

Comment: I always forget about `CONCAT` ... nicely done

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH col_data 
As 
    (SELECT cols = CASE WHEN colA IS NOT NULL THEN colA ELSE '' END
            + CASE WHEN colB IS NOT NULL THEN ': '+colB ELSE '' END
     FROM CTE
    )
  SELECT ISNULL(cols, '') from col_data;
```

Comment: instead of hard coding the values mentioned columnNames